# How to set Kendo UI grid page to all when assigning in Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo UI 2017. I currently am building it in Razor syntax. I am wondering since I have to set the page sizes by using a int[], how can I add the option All to this? Do I have to had it after page load, and then add it and do a refresh on the grid? That seems kind of a bad method to use.

```
 .PageSizes(new int[]{5, 10, 20, 25, 'All'}))  --> Fails because of int[] type obviously.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized after much thinking, but occurred right when I posted this. You can use a list type instead of int[].

```
.PageSizes(new List<object>{5, 10, 20, 25, 'All'}))
```